# Match a string between two characters if they exist

Tags: regex

I'm in need of an expression for finding a name in a dynamic path string.
Basically I need to find a string before last `>` character and it must be inside these `>` characters.
Lets say I have this string:

```
"Category 1 > Category 1.1 > Category 1.1.1"
```

With this expression `\>(.*)\>` it works, and I get the desired string which is `"Category 1.1"`.
The problem is if this string doesn't have a `>` at the beggining.
E.g.

```
"Category 1.1  > Category 1.1.1"
```

I tried something like this `\>?(?=>)?\>?(.*)\>` and this works but only for this case. When I test it with `"Category 1 > Category 1.1 > Category 1.1.1"`, it returns `Category 1 > Category 1.1 >` which is wrong.

Comment: Wait, do you expect `Category 1.1` in `Category 1.1  > Category 1.1.1`? Then, you may try `[^>]+(?=>[^>]*$)`.

Comment: It must return a category between > > characters or the string before last >. The problem is that this is dynamic. So with the last expression that you wrote the string 
Category 1 > Category 1.1 > Category 1.1.1 returns Category 1.1.1 which is wrong and it should return Category 1.1

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/WgjRra/1, in `Category 1 > Category 1.1 > Category 1.1.1`, I get a `Category 1.1` match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
[^>]+(?=>[^>]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WgjRra/1). For both the test cases you have, it matches `Category 1.1`  text.

**Details**

- `[^>]+` - 1+ chars other than `>`
- `(?=>[^>]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `>` and then 0+ chars other than `>` up to the end of the string.

Note you may want to `trim()` / `strip()`  the result afterwards with the appropriate method your environment provides.

Comment: @bruno_mikolaj Note I used `\n` in the demo only because the test is performed against a multiline string while in real life you will be using the regex against standalone strings.